# Proving that $L^p \cap L^{\infty} \supset L^r$ where $1 \leq p <r < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Suppose that $1 \leq p <r < \infty$.

Prove that $L^p \cap L^{\infty} \supset L^r$

I can prove this theorem for cases other than $\infty$ but not for those with $\infty$ .
Could you please guide me on how to proceed in the infinity case ?

Comment: What is the context here ? What is $L$ ?

Comment: @Astyx [Lp-spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space), I guess.

Comment: @Astyx The question was posted with the tag of lp-spaces whose standard notation is what I have used. Thus I didn't feel the need to clarify that $L^p$ stands for lp-spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. For instance, take your space to be $X=[1,\infty]$ with the standard measure, $r=2$, $p=1$, and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, then $f$ is in $L^2(X)=L^r(X)$, but $f$ is not in $L^1(X)=L^p(X)$.

Comment: You comment does not disprove that statement, because I want to show that $L^p \cap L^\infty \supset L^r$  , not that $L^p \supset L^r $

Comment: Yes it does, if it is in the intersection then it is in $L^p$.

Comment: I.e. $L^p \cap L^\infty \subset L^P$

Comment: This function I've described is not in $L^p$, so it cannot be in $L^p \cap L^\infty$.